# What should dad do if mom and toddler always fighting/tantrums etc

Tags: toddler

My second child (son) is almost 2 and he has tantrums daily. The tantrums are worse and more frequent than with my 1st (daughter). The tantrums are exclusively when we he is with mom or when mom is around. The tantrums are directed towards her. Most of the time the tantrum is because he doesn't get what he wants (a sweet snack or attention) but sometimes it is unclear what his deal is. Every time we go anywhere as a family the day is ruined because there are these 1 hour fights and tantrums or just him crying in the back of the car. Mornings start bad and days end bad. The days where we can all have peace at home are few and far between and I am constantly recovering from a bad mood because it hurts me to see my son behaving this way and also, perhaps less importantly, because I long for peace and harmony and feel happy when my kids are well behaved and happy themselves. It makes me very sad to see my son always crying.

What should I do as a father being around this constant fighting and tantrums. I used to get involved but whatever I do either doesn't work or make it worse because he just see mom and starts going crazy. They have this weird destructive relationship that makes both of them and the rest of us miserable. My father used to give me a hiding if I behaved half as bad as my son does which most will disagree with but I will say that I never behaved as bad as my son so what should I do as the father?

Comment: I have so many questions: Has he been checked by a doctor? May he be in pain? Toothing? Maybe food intolerance (lactose, gluten)? Is he trying to make progress in his development and you hold him back somehow. Does he have enough sleep? Have you checked all possible reasons for his behaviour?

Comment: You say "The tantrums are exclusively when we he is with mom", and "They have this weird destructive relationship that makes both of them and the rest of us miserable". It seems like something the Mom does could be one of the triggers. Could you please tell us more about their interactions/relationship? For example, does she give in to his tantrums, and you don't? Does she have a different parenting method than yours?

Comment: @Korinna Checked by a doctor for what? Maybe in 1% of cases it could have been that he was in "physical" pain but in most cases I think he is discovering that the world does not revolve around him and that mom has to wash dishes sometimes or give attention to other people.  The usual causes are that he doesn't get what he wants or that mom is busy and can't give him undivided attention. IMO it is not a medical thing that we should be thinking he needs a doctor (not yet anyhow), he want's things and thinks that mom is there to give everything that he wants and when she doesn't he acts up.

Comment: @learner Yes 100% exclusively with mom. We do have different parenting styles for sure. I am very firm and when I say no they usually listen without too much huff. Mom is a "softy", sometime he just sees her and begins crying. She is trying not to give in to the tantrums but he is very persistent and goes on and on. It is kind of like a competition where you see who gives in first and because he want's to break her and can sense his tantrum is affecting her emotionally so goes on. I think he gets some kind of reassurance from it because he tests her the whole time. What should I do?

Comment: @learner When I say no it is usually very straightforward but I sense that sometimes she feels guilty for saying no or when he is having a tantrum she feels bad for not giving in to his tantrums. I wonder if he can sense her guilt and feeds on it to give him reassurance because when he is having the fit and mom pays attention to someone else and ignores him he gets louder. Of course he does stop but it takes so long sometimes.

Comment: Is Mom the primary caregiver?  Is he in daycare/preschool/nanny/etc. or just with a parent?  Which one?  How old is the sister?

Comment: @Joe He is in day care and there is no "primary" caregiver. We are both around and both look after the kids but usually separately. We try go out on some weekends as a family but most times it turns into a big mess with 1 to sometimes even 2 or 3 tantrums. His sister is 3. She had a similar relationship with mom but she is better now and I think she has grown out of it. They are only 18 months apart. Please if you have any other questions, I don't mind answering any of them. I feel very lost and not sure what to do about it.

Comment: considering your other questions, I'd be tempted to say the relationship between you and your wife could be an underlying cause here.

Comment: @Rory that is very tempting indeed. Would it be tempting to explain how you get to that conclusion so I can know whether to consider your hypothesis?

Comment: @armani - your https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/34007/316 question. A significant cause of children acting up is when they don't get consistent messages from parents so they don't have a single framework of rules to work with (citation needed)

Comment: @Rory I have thought about this a lot and this makes complete sense but if one parent can't put the same limits as the other how is the other parent to achieve this framework alone? I don't see it as possible. Should the one parent now start lowering expectations to achieve this framework? Buy her a book? Unfortunately counseling here is expensive and there isn't anything low budget for us.

Comment: We do have a few questions here on this topic - it really does require you both to agree on limits/framework, and then stick to them. And support each other in this as it's not easy. It's almost certainly going to need compromise from you both.

Comment: @ Which questions? Yes I agree on that but for us to agree on a realistic framework would mean for me to start compromising on my own standards as a father. My wife is great at her job and she is very loving to her kids but with some things I am a lot better and the only way to achieve the framework is to do things how she does them not the way I do them. If she can't stop the tantrums must I just accept that and live with it?

Answer (score 5):

> What should I do as a father being around this constant fighting and tantrums.

Support your wife.

It seems to me that this is a battle between your wife and your son, and there's not a *lot* you alone can do.

As Joe discussed, do you discuss this with your wife? Why does she feel guilty when she's more firm with him? What is she trying to teach him with regards to behavior and love? (E.g. if she equates "love" with "making him happy", that leads to all sorts of problems.) Fundamental parenting issues (e.g. presenting a united front) should be solved together.

For handling tantrums, if nothing else, I recommend you read a book called [*1-2-3 Magic*](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_3?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=1-2-3+magic+effective+discipline+for+children+2-12&sprefix=1-2%2Caps%2C265&crid=36F3O9YQ8ISS6). It is about how to use time outs effectively, and it allows one to send a child to a time out without arguing or raising one's voice. Then, if you think it worthy to use, have your wife read it. Then start implementing it.<sup>*</sup> And 2 is a perfect time to start teaching the principle of time outs, which is not about punishment but about an opportunity to learn self control. <sup>**</sup>

It's essential to **be consistent** when implementing time outs (or setting any boundary, for that matter.) If he knows she will eventually give in, what harm is there in it for him to keep up his misbehavior? This is something else to discuss.

Now is also the time to be expanding his vocabulary with feeling words (in other words, give him an *emotional vocabulary*.) An emotional vocabulary is essential, but so often overlooked. **The first step to dealing with an emotion is learning to name it.** Adults often get angry because they feel worthless, powerless, hopeless, invalidated, disrespected, unloved, you name it, but they can't (name it), because dealing with primary emotions like worthlessness/being invalidated/feeling unloved is incredibly painful, so it becomes anger, which is easier to express and gives a false sense of control. If adults have difficulty with emotions because they are unaware of or unwilling to deal with primary emotions, imagine what it's like for a child.

Look at some online articles about emotional vocabularies. It will be very helpful. Practice using age-appropriate feeling words, and after a time out (or however you handle the tantrum), discuss the feelings that led to the tantrum. You might even learn how to avoid tantrums this way.

<sup>*</sup><sub>The way it works: Say X is doing something undesirable, for example, whining for ice cream before dinner. You say, "X, you can't have ice cream before dinner because (reasonable reason.) If you continue to ask for ice cream, you'll earn a time out." X keeps pleading. You start counting ("X, that's a one.") No fuss, no muss, no yelling, nothing but information. He hears you and keeps demanding, asking, "Whyyyyyyy can't I?" You continue to count ("X, that's a two.") No yelling/exasperation/anger involved. X continues: "Nooooooooo, I waaaaaant some NOW!" You finish ("O.K. honey, that's a three, time out.") Time outs are in a room alone without an audience. If you have to hold them down, the time out doesn't begin until they stay put on their own. Eventually **if you're consistent** they will learn that no means no, and that whining/other gets them nowhere. !!!**N.B.** **This is not a substitute for reading the book.** If you don't read the book, you'll miss out o all the excellent parenting advice in it.</sub>

<sup>**</sup><sub>This is what I used in our house, and it worked like, well, magic. My kids learned to control themselves very quickly and didn't argue or plead with me when I refused them something. When I started to count, they stopped what they were doing immediately, not because something terrible was about to happen, but because they knew my "no" was rock-solid and they were not going to change my mind. In light of that, I also tried to be wise with my "nos". I alsways told them why I was refusing them something as part of the process of giving/threatening time outs.</sub>

<sub>One of my children has a child of their own and another on the way. They plan on using 1-2-3 Magic as well, because they remember how effective it was.</sub>

Comment: Yes we discuss it, have discussed it a zillion times in every mood and in a thousand ways but it never changes anything. She realizes there is a problem but whatever I say or do makes no difference to her. She just can't manage him no matter how hard she tries and even friends/neighbors have gotten involved to try help her. As you said, I also feel like there is very little I can do but it hurts me to see my son having so many tantrums for so long and so often. It is the hardest thing for me to have to watch/listen to it because I can see him suffering.

Comment: So do you think I should just stay in the room and not speak while it goes on or do you think it is ok if I leave? Because it is too hard for me to watch it going on the whole time. Sometimes I get angry at her because I wish she could do more about it and toughen up with him.

Comment: Tantrums are one of the most difficult problems to manage in young children. I used to say it was easier managing life threatening events in the emergency room than handling a tantrum, because with emergencies, I knew exactly what to do. Not so with tantrums. However, you can't just walk away from this uncomfortable dynamic; people you love are negatively affected. If she won't listen to you or friends, have her consult an expert. Your child needs to know - with a lot of love and compassion - what is and isn't appropriate behavior. This is part of a life long process.

Comment: @anongoodnurese: She does want to go to a professional but we can't afford that. There seems to be a lot of great advice here about tantrums and how to stop them but I really was only looking for advice on how we should react as fathers in these cases when mom is the trigger. This may sound sad but I don't think the tantrums will go away. I think my son will grow out of them as did my daughter and am trying to prepare for the worst by seeking advice on how/where I should be in all this. You said: "you can't walk away" so what CAN I do? Support my wife? How? Go elsewhere to retain sanity?

Comment: the other day the whole park was looking at my son crying for 1 hr and all the other mums couldn't belive the spectacle that was unfolding before their eyes. My wife began crying in the park because he just would not stop. As a father, how are we supposed to react to this? I don't see any other things like this in public so can't say by seeing other people. These kind of tantrums don't happen anywhere else I have ever seen (honestly have seen a few but not like this). My wife, as good a mom as she is, does not know what to do in this area or how to diffuse the situation

Comment: There are free and very low-cost services for people who can't afford to pay for professional services. What can **you** do? Help your wife to set limits. Take over child care when she's becoming overwhelmed. Make sure she's getting adequate rest and alone time. Look for clues that a tantrum is coming, and if you can handle some, then do so. But you can't solve the problem between your wife and her child; that's her problem; she has to want to fix it. What you should **not** do: tell her she's wrong while it's happening. Undermine her. Make her less confident.

Comment: Were you at the park? I don't understand why your family stayed at the park while your child wasn't enjoying it. If any of mine started to throw a tantrum in public, they were immediately picked up and taken somewhere private (a car, or home) for a time out. Why would anyone stay until they were in tears? That makes no sense to me unless the adults are the ones who want to go to the park. Even then, if no one is enjoying themselves... You both need to figure out why this child has so much power over your wife's emotions. She's the adult in the pair and needs to be wiser.

Comment: @ anon: Ok I will keep this in mind. The thing I can't do is take over when she is overwhelmed because he wants her and nobody else exists. He will try dominate her and tries to bring her down by force or climbs her and even bites her sometimes or hits her. IMO his behaviour is abusive but can a child be abusive at that age? Can you even call it abusive? She doesn't set limits, she doesn't know how and it is making him worse. If you see these things as a father it destroys you and it has ruined my day a hundred or more times. I also hate to see my wife suffering so much.

Comment: yes we were all at the park that day and some of my wife's friends told her that what she should do is ignore him so she did but I agree with what you say, Park is for having fun, if not having a good time it should be home or time out. But time out is another issue with us because a lot of the times my wife is against it. She doesn't really believe in discipline. I know that that sounds crazy but she just doesn't. When she says she doesn't think time out works, I ask ok so what do you suggest and she says: "I don't know but timeout doesn't work"

Comment: What time-out strategy do you use? The reason I think my wife thinks time-out doesn't work is because she doesn't do it properly. According to her it makes my son worse.

Comment: "What time-out strategy do you use?" The answer is in my answer.

Comment: @armani, why don't you take the child away from the situation, and thus away from his mother? That would give them both a chance to calm down. From your comments it sounds like you just leave them both to go at it and go off by yourself to fume that she's not as perfect a parent in practice as you are in your mind.

Comment: @Aravis Because she is the one he wants, he goes mad. When I have tried to take him away, he doesn't stop crying for her because he feels like she is being taken away from him.  Also, I don't think that is the solution. So I shouldn't fume, what should I do in your opinion?

Answer (score 2):

I think that there are a lot of different things going on here that need to be addressed in different ways.  First, helping the child work out these issues, and second focusing on your relationship with his mother. (Sorry, this is going to be *long*.)

---

The first thing I'd say is to remember that your son is *two years old*.  Remember when you're having these interactions that he's not *trying* to misbehave; he's trying to learn how to navigate his environment, learn how to relate to people socially, and reacting to stimuli.  He's not any happier about these tantrums than you are. No two year old is going to be perfectly behaved in nearly any situation.

He's also a *second child*.  Don't compare him to your first - he's in a very different situation than she was. He's only 18 months younger, so she still needs a lot of attention herself; he gets probably 60% of the attention she got at this age. So it's not at *all* surprising that he's doing a lot to get your attention, and frustrated when he doesn't get it. You can't totally fix this - you don't have 200% of the attention you had before he was born, after all - but you need to take it into account.

Keep in mind when these things happen that your goal when resolving the tantrum is not to remove the annoying noise/spectacle/embarrassment caused by the tantrum, in most situations.  If you're in situations that are going to cause excessive embarrassment (at a theater, say), don't do that until you've worked through this period.

When they do happen, and there's both a clear problem and sufficient coherence from your son, focus on solving the problem. If he's screaming because he wants something, remember that at two, the ability to think about the future is *very* limited. He thinks that he's never going to get a sweet because you won't give him one right now. So help him learn to delay gratification. "Sorry Billy, you can't have a sweet right now because it's close to dinner. But I have a sweet for after dinner that's in my bag here." Then when after dinner happens, make a point to connect it to the earlier experience. This won't work instantly, but over time he'll begin to learn that "no right now" doesn't mean "no forever".

When they happen and there is *not* a clear problem or *not* sufficient coherence to work on it, focus on *destressing* the situation. Remove the focus on the trigger (if there is one). Focus on calming activities. Remove everyone to a quieter area, let the child express his emotions in a place you won't feel as uncomfortable, and be positive and calming. Remember, in these kinds of episodes the biggest issue is that the child cannot express himself effectively, so he resorts to crying and screaming.

---

Second is your relationship with his mother. You don't specify if you're married, but you say 'together as a family' so I'll treat it as if you are for purposes of this answer; it's not really important, so long as you're co-parenting, anyway.

Things like this need to be addressed through mutual discussion, understanding, and an agreement to proceed in a particular way. You and she need to talk together about how to deal with these situations, and need to come up with a way that works for both of you. This needs to come from *both* of you - not you telling her how to handle things; but you and she agreeing how to handle things. Sit down and have that discussion *now*, and at a time that isn't stressful.

My wife and I have these discussions *frequently*, and especially when we have particular things that frustrate either one of us. We both respect the other's viewpoint, and we don't tell each other what to do; we say what we think is the problem, then we each provide possible solutions and explanations for how to solve them - often researched in parenting books or papers. (She's a research scientist and I'm a research analyst, so perhaps we go overboard here...) We come to an agreement on how to handle things, and then implement that as best we can - understanding that we're not identical nor are we perfect and so we make mistakes, but we try to stick to what we agreed on, at least until it doesn't seem to work.

We also often discuss specific events after they occur - a while after, so the stress is gone, but not so far after that we don't remember the details (so maybe that night). If we had a particularly difficult issue, we talk about it, and how we could've done better. There are no recriminations here, and the way to get there is mostly for each parent to say how *they* could've done things better; telling your partner how they screwed up is a recipe for disaster. But if you are both able to talk about how things went, and then ask the partner for suggestions for how to improve next time, it can be very fruitful.

It's also important to ask how *you* can help *her* in situations like this. She may appreciate it if you intervene in certain ways; my wife for example appreciates it when I recognize that she's losing her temper, and I find a way to step in and remove one of the children from the situation (We have two 19 months apart, similar to yours). But she doesn't appreciate it when I come in and start telling the kids what to do directly - as I may be not understanding what she's trying to do. We've talked about this several times, and I've learned how I can be *helpful* instead of just taking over and inserting my judgement for hers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. While there is a lot of great general and helpful info there I don't see how it is relevant to the problem I am having. When my son has a tantrum it is directed to mum and the whole rest of the world disappears. Meaning, I could yell or a bomb could go off and he wouldn't notice or care he just sees and thinks mum mum mum and goes ape so she will pay attention to him or give him what he wants (depending on the cause of the tantrum). My question was, how do I deal with this? This is what I am still not clear on so please help me. So I ignore it, leave, say: stop!?